# Execution failed for task ':app:signingConfigWriterDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently I have faced the following problem. When I have just built the project with another user-account before and the permissions were not inherited from a parent directory. It shows an error like that:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Projects\PracticeApp\app\build\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json
```

What is the reason? How can I solve it ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At last the solution I found: I try to change signing-config.json properties and it works.

- open \build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out.
- then right click on signing-config.json and open properties.
- go to security tab and click advance button.
- Then click the security
- click change owner
- add your active windows user and apply
- open file properties one more time, go to the Security tab.
- Now select the user and edit the access permission all read write.

I have followed this link [link](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1822) and it works now for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Setting permissions on `Projects` or `PracticeApp` might rather make sense; then inherit from there... because if you run the `:clean` task, you might have to set these permissions again.

Comment: Thank you Martin. Your answer make really good sense but it works for me even after cleaning ! But may be it will be better to set permission for project.

Comment: Probably you've just built the project with another user-account before and the permissions were not inherited from a parent directory... just stated it, because both of these situations can cause the issue. Setting permission for group users would make it work for all users.

Comment: simply delete the `signing-config.json` file and try to run the project again.

Answer (score 7):

I also faced the same problem, and the solution was to run the command

```
flutter clean
```

and then

```
flutter run
```

Comment: I had this issue after reinstalling windows and then when I try to run this project. So clean and run works fine.

Comment: It was the same with me. After installing windows I did not run the code

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the following is a solution

1. open \build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out.
2. delete the file, signing-config.json.
   That's it. Rebuild and Run the project.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was:

- Open the terminal in vscode
- Type the command flutter clean
- Fixed

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following helped me

1. Clean Project
2. Run 'app'